# How to do a method search programmatically in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, search, plugins

I wrote an Eclipse plugin that ends up with a method name and I want display the method search results for the user exactly as they would have gotten from the built-in Java Search dialog as if they typed the the method name themselves.  This way when users click on a method in the results, the method is revealed in the editor.  Ideally, I just want to use the existing functionality.

I know how to use `SearchEngine` which is GUI'less and learned a bit about `NewSearchUI.runQueryInForeground(null, query)` and started implementing `ISearchQuery` and `ISearchResult`, but that is now leading toward having to implement `ISearchResultPage` which is effectively writing my own GUI.  This is way overboard for something Eclipse already does well.

I am missing something.  This should be trivial.  I am grateful for any advice.

Comment: Actually not trivial because all the Java search code is in `internal` packages in the JDT and consequently is not available for use.

Comment: How is your plugin different from the user right clicking on the method name and selecting Search -> Java from the main menu?